# Star Wars: Assault Team - Arena - Never get any trophies

Tags: star-wars-assault-team

I have won 90%+ of my battles in Star Wars: Assault Team (Windows 8) and I've yet to win a trophy, so I can only ever get through one battle at a time. All of the leagues (SILVER, GOLD, PLATINUM, DIAMOND) are permanently locked.

Am I missing some trick/setting somewhere?

Comment: I'm seeing this issue as well, very annoying.

Comment: Same here. But today I got attacked for the first time in a month.